# Walking Through AST ANTLR v2.x

Tags: java, antlr

Can someone please tell me how to Walk Through the AST with java  ANTLR v2.x (i.e without using commontree)

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is vague.  The standard way to process trees with ANTLR is to write a tree grammar to correspond to the tree the parser builds.  Plenty of examples are at http://www.antlr2.org/doc/index.html.